# Operator '&&' can't be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'

Tags: c#, int, boolean, operators

im trying to find out if a number that is entered is both divisible by 9 and 13, but it wont let me use the operator i need, i know the variable types are wrong but i dont know how to make it so that the variable types are accepted, im new to coding so can the answer be as basic as possible without taking the piss

```
public bool IsFizzBuzz(int input)
{
    if ((input % 9) && (input % 13) == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: something like `if((input%9 == 0) && (input%13==0))`

Comment: Something to think on for the future... Look at what you are doing- you know what `%` does (or so it seems) so you know that this `input%9` has to evaluate to something, so you need to evaluate what you think it will evaluate to (in this case 0)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since [`==` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx) has [higher precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691323%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) than [`&&` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx), your if statements calculates first;

```
(input % 13) == 0
```

part and that returns `true` or `false` depends on your `input`. And your if statement will be like;

```
(input % 9) && true // or false
```

since `input % 9` expression returns `int`, at the end, your if statement will be;

```
int && true
```

and logical AND is meaningless between `int` and `bool` variables.

From [`&&` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx)

> The conditional-AND operator (&&) performs a logical-AND of its **bool
>   operands**, but only evaluates its second operand if necessary.

You said;

> im trying to find out if a number that is entered is both divisible by
>   9 and 13

Then you should use them like;

```
if ((input % 9 == 0) && (input % 13 == 0))
```

Comment: Many +1's for detail and explanation :D

Answer (score 4):

You cant compare two bracketed statements against one comparison you have to do something like the following.

```
if( (input % 9 == 0) && (input % 13 == 0) )
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because the `&&` operator has a higher priority than the `==` operator, so the statement is evaluated like this:

```
if (((input % 9) && (input % 13)) == 0)
```

Not like this:

```
if ((input % 9) && ((input % 13) == 0))
```