# Operator '&&' can't be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool' (minimum difference)

Tags: c#, if-statement

i am trying to find out the  minimum difference between three integers. And it says:"Operator '&&' can't be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'".
Where i am wrong?

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number1, number2;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter three numbers.");
        int x= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int y= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int z= int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if(Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(y-z) && Math.Abs(x-z))
        {
            number= x;
            number= y;
        }
        else if....
```

Comment: Well, it can't be - what exactly (in mathematical terms) are you trying to accomplish there?

Comment: I believe you are trying to say... if x-y is less than y-z and x-y is less than x-z, you are currently saying if x-y is less than y-x and x-z which doesn't make sense to the computer.

Comment: `Math.Abs(x-z)` is the problem. When you use the `&&` operator it is expecting an expression on left and on the right that are bool. `Math.Abs(x-z)` is not a bool.

Comment: Looks like you're missing the second part of the second condition.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to do this: `if(Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(y-z) && Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(x-z))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Operator '&&' can't be applied to operands of type 'int' and 'bool'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27156668/operator-cant-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-int-and-bool)

Comment: Please at least search for the error message before posting on Stack Overflow, as it says in [ask].

Comment: This is simple, but common, wrongthink.  You're thinking of it like "If a is less than b and c", but C# doesn't work that way. You have to explicitly state "if a is less than b and if a less than c".

Comment: Another way to write that would be `if(Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Min(Math.Abs(y-z), Math.Abs(x-z)))`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is with `Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(y-z) && Math.Abs(x-z)`, specifically `&& Math.Abs(x-z)`.

I assume what you're trying to say is that |x - y| < { |y - z| , |x - z| }
or, in other words, the absolute value of x-y is less than the absolute value of y-z and also the absolute value of x-z.

< is an operator that takes two operands, in this case, two ints. && is another operator that takes two bool operands. To be able to express what you were trying to do, the && operator would have to be able to do more than just bools, because right now your && has a bool and int around it. This shows this a little clearer...

```
bool isLessThan = Math.Abs(x - y) < Math.Abs(y - z);
if (isLessThan && Math.Abs(x - z))
{
    ...
}
```

The if statement will have an error because the && operator doesn't know how to compare a bool and int.
You should change it to this to fix it...

```
int xMinusY = Math.Abs(x - y);
if (xMinusY < Math.Abs(y - z) && xMinusY < MAth.Abs(x - z))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int number1, number2;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter three numbers.");
        int x = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int y = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        int z = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        if ((Math.Abs(x - y) < Math.Abs(y - z)) && (Math.Abs(x - y) < (Math.Abs(x - z))
        {
            number1 = x;
            number2 = y;
        }
```

You can resolve this problem like this.

Comment: Please add some explanation of why/how this code helps the OP. This will help provide an answer future viewers can learn from. See [this Meta question and its answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256359/215552) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Math.Abs(x-z) on its own does not resolve to a boolean. If you are intending to use the integer representations of a boolean (0 is false, !0 is true) just cast

```
if(Math.Abs(x-y) < Math.Abs(y-z) && Convert.ToBoolean(Math.Abs(x-z)))
```

Comment: First I don't think that's what the OP wanted.  Second C# does not allow casts from `int` to `bool` like C and C++.  Instead you'd have to use `Convert.ToBoolean`.

Comment: Well im not sure how to divine what the original poster wanted but you are right about the (bool). i fixed that

Comment: I've seen people make that mistake a lot, not sure why.

Comment: i was honestly just thinking ive done it before. i am either misremembering (possible) or maybe it worked at some point but was depricated?